# What's the right way to self-answer if other answers assisted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, accepted-answer, attribution

After I asked a question that included some sample code, someone answered with a possible solution that wasn't quite what was wanted.  After a little back-n-forth in comments, they edited their answer to include something that was closer, but still not quite right.

However, their answer did give me an idea and I ended up solving the original problem with a solution that was closest to the code originally posted in the question but with some minor changes inspired by the other answer.

I posted how I *actually* solved the problem as a separate answer, for future reference.  But which answer deserves the tick?  My answer was ultimately "more correct" (admittedly I'm probably biased there) but I probably wouldn't have thought of the solution without the other answer, and I want them to get some points for it, and more than just an upvote.

For the moment I've ticked their answer to give them the points, but I'm not sure that's "right" since ultimately it wasn't the solution used.  Am I correct in assuming that if I change it to tick my answer, they'll lose the points?  Any way to avoid that?

(Granted by now the points don't *really* matter, but it's the principle of the thing.)

Comment: What you could do is to keep his answer accepted and wait for the folks to choose. If your answer gets a lot more upvotes, then it is better and you could mark it as accepted. But IMO general answers are better than specialized ones.

Comment: That's why I preferred my answer -- it was more general/flexible. :)

Comment: If you _really_, _desperately_ want to reward the other answer, there is a bounty option which is (questionably) appropriate (Reward existing answer)

Comment: Quote and credit.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Addition to answer. Self answer or comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388037/11107541), and [Should I include the working code after I have resolved an issue using more than one of the answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305906/11107541)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Marking an answer as accepted is supposed to represent that that answer ultimately solved your problem. Marking an answer that **did not** solve your problem (and leaving it that way) will **mislead future users** who are also having the same problem, and are trying to find a solution.

What I would do in your case is to **just link to the other person's answer**, mentioning that their answer inspired yours, and other people may give it a few upvotes then. You can even make your own answer into a **community wiki**, if you feel that you personally don't deserve any reputation from upvotes for (partially) using someone else's idea.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you've said, but it still feels like depriving the other answerer of points.  Possibly this is just a personal hangup I should get over; both of us have over 1k anyway and the tick is only worth 15, which is just a drop in the bucket.

Comment: @Miral: Don't mark it accepted if it didn't solve your problem. Acknowledge the merits of the answer and your troubleshooting steps that led you to your answer so it helps potential future readers. If it makes you feel better, leave a comment on the unaccepted answer thanking the original person but you found a better solution.

Comment: @Miral If those answers were useful *upvote* them. If you feel they deserve more points *open a bounty* and attribute it to their answers.

Comment: @Cupcake One thing to keep in mind is that, oftentimes the answer that inspired the OP actually provides the correct solution well within the scope of the question title and description. It's just that sometimes OP got caught up in the moment and didn't provide enough details to let others fully solve the problem (not to mention misleading or wrong info altogether). In this particular case, not marking the answer feels wrong, IMO. For me, I would first look back at the title and description, and if such answer is correct for the given info, I will still mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Looks like a clear consensus.  Ok, I'll do that. :)

Answer (score 4):

Mark the answer that solved your problem. If you feel the other answer deserves more points, there are always bounties.

Comment: If I'm reading the bounty rules right, now that the question has a self-answer the minimum bounty is 100 points.  Given that a tick is 15 points, I'm not sure the other answer helped *that* much.  (Also, adding a bounty has a minimum time before it can be awarded, which is clearly intended to increase views and is useless as a reward system for an existing answer.)

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is: why isn't there a system independent of bounties that allows the questioner to arbitrarily hand out *any* small number of points to answers that they deemed helpful, even if they were not the final solution?  (Yes, there's a single upvote available, but sometimes that's too limited.)

Answer (score 3):

> For the moment I've ticked their answer to give them the points,

SO is not just because of points. you just need to consider the SO intention : **The answer is marked will be the closest or best among all the answers and it should be useful for the  other users , who are looking for the same situation.** . Let them promote as well.

Comment: I know that, which is why I wasn't happy with just leaving their answer ticked.  I suppose I can just tick my answer and throw up my hands and say "the points don't matter anyway" but that doesn't feel right either.  (In my experience, given two answers on a question, people will only upvote one of them, even if both are helpful and even if the "best" answer depended on the answerer reading another answer first.)

Comment: I should possibly add that there is no question of correctness or competition; the other answerer admitted that my answer is better, and I admitted that I would not have thought of it had I not been inspired by their answer.  So I would expect that left to upvotes alone, my answer would get all the votes.  But that doesn't seem "fair" to the other answerer.

Comment: Yes, you'r right . Let's wait for the votes. and just pick it off, don't worry too much about your answer or someone's. let the SO users decide in this type of situation

Comment: "*The answer is marked will be the closest or best among all the answers*" This is quite **incorrect**. Accepted answers **do not have to be the *best* answer**, they just represent what solved the asker's problem, though many people will often later on change the accepted answer to one which has been the most upvoted or is a better solution... **but that is not required**.

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, I agree. but this type of situation , If he doesn't have answer, then what you said is right .

Comment: @Miral I agree with Kumar here. Do **not** let the fact that there is a somewhat competitive reward system influence your decisions. That system is intended to help StackOverflow achieve it's real goal: answering questions. Upvotes are for answers users think contribute useful information. Acceptance is for an answer that solves your problem. By that criteria, your answer deserves to be accepted and the other upvoted (by you). SO doesn't guarantee reward for effort, and the reward should not be the asker's or answer's priority. It's a mindset. Be appreciative, but use the site appropriately.

Comment: @Cupcake That is what I interpret to be the "best answer". It could be the best answer to life, but if it doesn't solve my problem then it's as good as no answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) has:

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally ....

So I disagree with much of what else has been written here. There is fair warning that the answer with the green tick is **not** necessarily the best - obvious really since it can only be a subjective view (unlike voting that represents a collective view).

Q&A's are a means to an end (not just unicorn points). One has a problem, someone else solves it. The 'fix' might be advice, code, a link etc but whatever method, somebody has bothered to help you out and you deemed that help constructive. That is what the tick is for.

If you are unhappy about the quality don't upvote. It is the votes that attempt to indicate quality, the accepts are basically just "thank you".

Since posting your own answer you can explain why it is that your own is not the one you accepted but

Leave your tick where it is.

Comment: So I'm a little confused, are you saying that the original poster should mark the other answer as accepted as a means of saying "Thank you", even though it ultimately wasn't the solution to his problem? If so, I'd have to disagree with you, because I would find that very confusing, as another user having the same problem, and trying to find a solution for it.

Comment: So I agree that upvotes ultimately more meaningfully represent an answer's quality than an accept mark, but I'm still going to have to disagree about using an accept mark to "say Thanks" on an answer that didn't ultimately solve the original poster's problem.

Answer (score -1):

In a minor, but similar, case I had, I [edited my solution into the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13591813/6) and accepted it.

I’m not sure how that applies to your specific case, but in general this is an option I’d keep in mind. This edit seems to have been disputed upon review, but I for my self think that this is legit.