# Valid edit rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I made an edit to an answer I was using and then after finding another bug, I made another edit for it to work properly. The edit was made after running the code and checking it works properly. But 3 reviewers rejected the answer with an irreleveant reason and 2 approved and the edit got rejected. I know the answer is wrong. But, can do nothing because someone rejected the edit. The edit in question is:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5418110

I posted a comment to point to the correct answer. What can be done here?

Comment: might be technically right, but you were changing someone else's answer; putting words into their mouths (post) as it were.  If you think it is wrong, downvote and post your own answer explaining how it is superior.

Comment: Commenting on the error is one thing that can be done. The second is answering the question with your own answer. Editing someone else code isn't welcome.

Comment: @Plutonix Mine was not superior.I was using the answer for my problem. But, found a couple of problems in the answer and so wanted to make the answer correct.

Comment: So, thats not a substantial improvement. I change dthe regex to do modulo instead of comparison. My answer would be a duplicate. Its redundancy.

Comment: No it wouldn't be a duplicate or redundant. The answer you used is doing X and your answer is doing Y. They are quite different even if the syntax is similar.

Comment: And can someone please shed light on all the downvotes? Isnt meta to ask such questions?

Comment: the DVs are just signalling disagreement with your position/premise.  Here, most likely the notion of "valid edit"

Comment: @theshadowmonkey meta is different from the main site; votes are more about agreement and disagreement with the contents, not about the quality or the on-topicness of a question.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Thanks. I left a comment. Ill probably leave it there.

Comment: [What's the right way to self-answer if other answers assisted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262210/1248008) might be related

Comment: You didn't know if the edit was valid or not. Declaring it so in the title may warrant downvotes...

Comment: Can I close this question now?

Comment: Not really, no. Why would you?

Comment: @Bart The intended purpose of the question is complete and my question was very specific to a particular case and why should it be kept open?

Comment: If the "purpose is complete" you can accept an answer. Which you've done. No need to close anything. That's not what it's for and not how it works.

Comment: That implies you think a question's life is over when _you_ get _your_ answer. On the contrary: Stack Exchange is not a suite of personal helpdesks. Your question shall remain here to assist others in the future with similar issues, or to be used as a duplicate, or to be referred to as a reference by others. It's not just about you.

Comment: even if the edit is considered "not valid" here @theshadowmonkey didn't apply any wrong edit, here in meta the op is questioning about how to solve a real world situation which can't be understood by reading the books/docs. So the matter of this meta question in my opinion makes the question a good question!! so should I upvote or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't be making substantial **functional** edits to someone else's answer.

If you come up with a better answer, post it as a new answer (citing the original if you based it on another).

Comment: "If you come up with _what you think is_ a better answer" *  OP assumes he's right. OP may not be right. That's the crux of it, really.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to leave a comment (and possibly downvote) below the answer, if my edit would be changing any functionality, but is still too minor to be worth a new answer (besides, I don’t like basing my answer on others).

As a bonus, in the case I was wrong, maybe because I overlooked a subtlety in the question or the code posted in the answer, the poster can explain that in fact *I* was wrong, in an informal, less competetive manner.