# What answer should I mark as accepted?

Tags: discussion

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288328/nuget-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-504-gateway-timeout?noredirect=1#comment45091495_28288328) what was I supposed to mark as an answer ? probably all are good (didn't tested all) also the problem is not longer happening but may happen again so the question is valid for future errors people might have.

Maybe I should leave that question without an accepted answer?

I read about [similar question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262210/whats-the-right-way-to-self-answer-if-other-answers-assisted) but for this case there's no correct  or more closely correct answer, all solve the problem in different ways.

Comment: It's your choice.

Comment: You have a correct answer for this question, you discovered that this was a temporary outage server-side.  So post that conclusion yourself and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Asking on meta is so frustrated with all of the downvotes. It took me a lot of thinking about asking because of this. Next time I will do whatever it pleases me. The amount of information received is invaluable but the downvotes makes me not want to use meta again.

Answer (score 1):

By accepting an answer you verify that this procedure solved exactly your problem.

If none of them actually solved your problem (because you did not test them, ...) you do not have to accept an answer.

Comment: the problem disappeared (it got resolved server side I think) so no, I had no chance to test any of the proposed solutions.

Comment: @Bart Then do not accept an answer - none of them solved your problem. If you find out what changed on the server, and it is described in one of the answers you can still accept this answer.

Comment: This isn't strictly accurate. The expectation isn't that an accepted answer is verified to exactly solve the stated problem - accepting an answer is just supposed to indicate that the asker felt that that answer was the most helpful. I'm looking for a clear source on that.