# Should I include the working code after I have resolved an issue using more than one of the answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

Or would that make it too specific to my issue. It seems to me other people with similar issues would find it more helpful than going through all the answers.

Comment: That's very useful but not required, as well as answerers are not required to include full working code.

Comment: Older cross-site dup on MSE: [Is it appropriate to answer one's own question with code derived from another answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107001/997587).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would indeed suggest to post an own answer. Give attribution to the users you derived an answer from and make sure it is more than just a code dump of the working code. The answer should really stand on its own.

I would also suggest accepting the answer that helped you best if your work is a derivative from that answer, not your own. An exception can be made if your post is *much* better than the work you derived your answer from.

Never post working code as a comment or an edit of your question. That isn't the place for answers.