# Addition to answer. Self answer or comment?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question about some code, and I got a good answer. But i have addition to code. I should self-answer with full code and mark it? Or comment answer?

Comment: It depends, IMO. How significant is your addition? Are you adding one keyword to ten lines of code? A complete implementation to a one line snippet? How divergent will be your answer from the existing one in the end?

Comment: You have only two non-closed questions, you may as well be specific and point to the question and the answer you want to improve upon.

Comment: I’d accept the other answer, upvote it, then post your own answer, which should start out immediately and explicitly saying “Building on @OtherUser’s very helpful answer (link to his answer), I created a more complete solution this: ...”. That way credit where credit is due, and the community benefits also from a more comprehensive answer, while giving the original answer the head start it earned.

Comment: @DanBron Best to write this up as an answer, perhaps, to give it the same "weight" as the other two suggestions? (Because this is what I think is the more morally correct approach in most cases.)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Should I include the working code after I have resolved an issue using more than one of the answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305906/11107541)

Answer (score 5):

Self-answer.  Your addition is a standalone response to the answer.  Be sure to add attribution to whoever provided most of the answer for you.